# Eliminate from list of sets those that are equal (except for the order)

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sets

I have a list of sets and some of them are equal in the sense of mathematics, but are ordered differently. How can I remove those elements from my list?

For example, the set

`S=Tuples[{1, -1}, {2, 3}]`

contains `{{1,1,1},{1,1,-1}}` and `{{1,1,-1},{1,1,1}}`. I want only the first of them.

This means that I want to eliminate from a set of matrices those with the same set of lines, but ordered in a different way.

The code have to work with any set generated through `Tuples`. (I my case, a small set of `9 x 9` matrices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 10.0, you can use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) with any arbitrary function to define the "Sameness". Both the function and operator form are available.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@S
```

From version 7.0 onward you could do

```
DeleteDuplicates[S, Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &]
```

As correctly pointed out by *Bob Hanlon* in the comments.

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In versions prior to v10, `DeleteDuplicates[S, Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &]`

Comment: Is there a simple way to gather numbered elements (like `w1`, `w2`, `w3`, ..., `w32`) into a list (like `{w1, w2, w3, ..., w32}`)?

Comment: @Filburt you should post another question and explain what you mean there, in detail.

Comment: @rhermans Okay =D